# Does the interpreted nature of JavaScript/Jquery increase code size when a function is binded to many links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, optimization

I am having many urls (50 or more) in a table. I am overloading the click event for each of this link by selecting all anchor tags under its parent class.

```
$(".mapURL a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = ($(this).attr('href'));
    fetchMapByURL(url);
});
```

**Since JavaScript in interpreted languages does this imply that the following piece of code would be generated 50 times (to be bounded with each anchor tag) thereby making it inefficient and increasing the memory usage on client side**

> Edit - The function fetchMapByURL(url) is a larger function (30 lines) that makes a ajax call to an API to get an image and load it on the canvas. Should I still not be bother about it?

Please elaborate your answer with as much technical details as possible.

Comment: jQuery isn't a language. It's just a library (a thing with lots of prebuilt functions in it).

Comment: Yes, it does mean that. However 50 elements isn't anything to worry about. You won't generally notice an issue up to several thousand elements with event handlers, depending on the spec of the client machine. If you're that concerned about it you can use a single delegated event handler on a parent element to achieve this, but then you need to be careful of events bubbling.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: There's only *one* function above, not 50.

Comment: Right, but it's added to each element matching `.mapURL a` in the DOM, hence it's added Nelement times. See the `each()` at the bottom of the `on()` method: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=on.  Admittedly browsers may be smart enough to recognise the same function logic being applied multiple times, it appears that jQuery is not, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Again: 50 references, not 50 functions. I'm sure you understand the difference between `$(...).each(function() { $(this).click(function() { ... }); });`, which creates a new function on each iteration, and that `each` within `on`, which *reuses* the function. The `each` in that code doesn't create new functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the interpreted nature of JavaScript...

JavaScript isn't "interpreted" by nature. It's just that in the common environments (browsers, Node), it's delivered in source form to the target environment. All modern JavaScript engines compile the code to machine code whenever there's a benefit to doing so. There's also at *least* one JavaScript compiler that lets you compile source code and ship bytecode instead of source to the target environment (in that case, the Rhino compiler — now a bit obsolete — targeting the JVM).

> ...does this imply that the following piece of code would be generated 50 times...

No, you have **one** handler function attached to 50 elements in that code, not 50 separate handler functions.

Even if you did it the wrong way and created 50 functions:

```
// WRONG, for illustration purposes
$(".mapURL a").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = ($(this).attr('href'));
        fetchMapByURL(url);
    });
});
```

...while 50 different function objects would be created (each taking a tiny bit of memory), the JavaScript engine will reuse the *code* across those 50 function objects. (The code here is so small that there's probably not a lot of benefit to that, but...)

But 50 function objects is no big deal; we use objects all over the place in JavaScript, and they're highly-optimized things with smallish baseline footprints. You'd have to be into at least the tens if not hundreds of thousands before it would show up in your performance metrics as something to worry much about in most modern environments.

But that doesn't matter for your code, which only has a single handler function reused across elements.

---

> The function `fetchMapByURL(url)` is a larger function that makes a ajax call to an API to get an image and load it on the canvas. Should I still not be bother about it?

Your handler is **calling** that function. It doesn't matter how many different places a function is *called* from, there's still just the one copy of it (unless you create more, see "wrong" above).

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation but the function is pointing to a large function so I need to be sure that it doesn't create 50 objects but reuse only single piece of code everytime . (Please refer to the edit)

Comment: @Harvey: That's fine, it doesn't. You're using a **single** handler function (because you're not doing it the "wrong" way shown above, which sometimes people do). But (now I've looked at the edit), the edit just says you're *calling* a bigger function; calling it doesn't duplicate it.

Comment: Apologies for being paranoid but as Rory mentioned above in comments There is each() at the bottom of the on() method: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=on. Are you still sure it's just one handler function?

Comment: @Harvey: Yes, quite certain. It's **one** function, with multiple references to it.